# Content Script Error for Google Extension

Tags: javascript, json

For some reason, both my text editor and Google keep highlighting the colon in my sixth line. I've searched for questions related, but I haven't found anything similar.  Help?

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "kittenbook",
    "description": "Replace photos on Facebook with kittens",
    "version": "0.0.1"
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*//www.facebook.com/*"],
            "js": ["kittenbook.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing comma:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "kittenbook",
  "description": "Replace photos on Facebook with kittens", 
  "version": "0.0.1",//This was missing
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "//www.facebook.com/"
      ],
      "js": [
        "kittenbook.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response!!!! But I don't think that's the problem, because when I loaded it the first time before the content script, it had no problem. I keeps highlighting the line that says: "content_scripts": [

Comment: Look at your example, after the `version property` you missed the `,` and was throwing an error at `content_scripts` as it was not valid json.

Comment: But now it's saying "invalid value" and "missing scheme separator".  Any ideas?